# Deploy dtsx from visual studio 2013 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

It's possible to deploy one package SSIS(.dtsx) created on visual studio 2013 on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: No. Backwards compatibility is not a feature in SSIS

Comment: It's possible, but it's not guaranteed to work.   You might get lucky though.